# javascript alternative "filter some", for nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, nested

##### Hi,

###### To filter various data at the same time in the following table,

###### I'm trying to find an simple alternative to avoid nested loops for this scenario :

```
const carsList = 
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name" : "Fiat",
      "description" : "blabla",
      "options": [
          {
              "option" : "electric windows",
              "quantity" : 4
          },
          {
              "option" : "air bags",
              "quantity" : 2
          }
       ]
      }
    ]


// value = e.target.value;

result = carsList.filter(
  (car) =>
    car.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()) ||
    car.description.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()) ||
    car.options.some((option) =>
      option.option.toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toString().toLowerCase())
    )
);
```

---

###### also to filter with an array of values ( tagsExist ( the id's are the names ) ) ​​as follows :

```
let tagsExist = [...document.querySelectorAll('#tags [id]')].map((elm) => elm.id);

resultResearchInPage = carsList.filter((element) =>
  tagsExist.every(
    (x) =>
      element.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(x) ||
      element.description.toString().toLowerCase().includes(x) ||
      element.options.some((option) => option.option.toString().toLowerCase().includes(x))
  )
);
```

###### the "some" in the "filter" are problematic, could you help me, please ?

Comment: I specify that the data are not these, but that the structures are identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is feasible for you, I would suggest transforming the `options` array of the `carList` to an object, declaring as key the `option` variable, and as value the `quantity` (or an object if you will need more attributes). Then you can check if `option in options`, being options something like:

```json
"options":{
   "air bags":{
      "quantity": 2
   },
   ...
}
```

This will be checked in linear time, as key checks work similarly as with hashmaps, instead of having to loop through the whole array.

However this will only work if you have unique keys for the options and if you can transform the array to an object without more performance problems than this solution will solve.

Comment: thank you very much to you, I will dig to see how it fits, and how to add it later to the other filters :)

Comment: I tried to give you a 'like', but I'm new to the platform and I have to wait to collect reputation points

Comment: there will be data that will not be unique, so there would be no other solutions ?

Comment: I can only think of keeping the keys as they are, but changing the content to an array instead of an object. You will still need to loop the array, but if there are not many items sharing the same key, it could save you some time. However, your filter right now only needs to check if there is some option with a given name, so you could check `key in options` and `options[key]` not empty (if you need to filter for additional `option` fields then you might need to loop the list of options that share the key). I cannot figure out other solution. Hope helps!

Comment: that's nice of you, thanks a lot :)